# pytest remove a test from results

Tags: pytest

I've added some extra tests I can run if I need some info about the runners, but they fill up metadata used in test presentation, so they should not show up as a standalone test:

```
pytest.exe .\tests\test_01_services_up.py --webhost=test1 -k test00
====== test session starts =====
: <lots of info>
tests/test_01_services_up.py::TestClass::test00_runner_info PASSED
```

We use pytest-html, pytest-html-reporter, jenkins, gitlab-ci and some homegrown tests-report frameworks, so manually adding code to remove it in all report-frameworks is impractical.

Is there a way to create a fixture in conftest.py that removes the test, like using a `@pytest.mark.hookwrapper` or some internal not very prominently documented feature.